# ASP.NET - Accessing Session Variables from an outside application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session

I am trying to write a web service in ASP.NET which enables an outside application to access Session Variables such as the users that is currently logged in.

I thought that a correct way to do so would be to pass a cookie with a SessionID to the web service (or the SessionID itself), and have the web service return parameters of the Session object.

However, after a prolonged search I could not find a way to access Session variables with just a SessionID. Is this true? If so, is there an alternative way for me to write a service that will access session variables?

Thank you,

Comment: I think you will need to go to storing your sessions in the DB (instead of InProc); then you can query that session information directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off-hand, if you're using SQL session storage you could just query the session database by session id...

```
select
 s.[SessionItemShort]
,s.[SessionItemLong]
from [ASPStateTempSessions] as s
where s.[SessionId] = @sessionId
```

iirc, SessionItemShort is a varbinary while SessionItemLong is an image... if the session item is larger than a varbinary(7000) it'll get stored in SessionItemLong instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have attribute `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` for your web method?

[Session Variables and Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140627/session-variables-and-web-services)

Also, you can do Cookieless Sessions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx