# Using public property between web service methods

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I want to define a property in asmx web service that shared between all web methods.
this is my question:

Code:

```
myWS test1 = new myWS();
test1.SetToken(UserID1);
test1.AnotherMethod();


//stuff...

myWS test2 = new myWS();
test2.SetToken(UserID2);
test2.AnotherMethod();
```

Webservice:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://test.ir/")]
public class myWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public string Token { get; set; }

    Public void SetToken(int UserID){
      this.Token= BLL.GetToken(UserID);
    }

    Public void AnotherMethod(){
      BLL.CheckToken(Token);//i want token value be per every myWS web service defined
    }
 }
```

notes:
* static property is not good,because is share between all users,i want token value be unique in every myWS test = new myWS()

thanks.

Edits:

My app runs on a pc in every user start up and all instance call my web service

Comment: I don't get it. What's wrong with your current implementation? Token is an instance variable so it is different for every instance of myWS

Comment: Think he wants session based authentication.

Comment: @alessiobortolato: i fill token in first method,but when call second,the token property is null,this sounds that every web method request has it's property and mean only in that request, my app run on a pc in every user start up and all instance call my web service

Comment: Try using a session enviroment. Take a look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140627/session-variables-and-web-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that any instance of web service is unique.
we resolved this by sending param to our methods,associate that to a public property and use in other methods of that instance of web service.

Webservice:
[WebService(Namespace = "http://test.ir/")]

```
public class myWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public string Token { get; set; }

    Public void SetToken(string myToken){
      this.Token= myToken;
    }

    Public void Method1(){
      BLL.CheckToken1(Token);
    }

    Public void Method2(){
      BLL.CheckToken2(Token);
    }
 }
```

call:

```
myWS test1 = new myWS();
test1.SetToken("abc");
test1.Method1();
test1.Method2();
```